# How to add c++ library path in to xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, shared-libraries

I am using C+ library Ex:sample.lib. Now I want to add this library path in to **Other linker flag** in xcode.

I added like this

```
-L/(library path) -llibsample
```

or

```
-L/(library path) -lsample
```

or

```
-L/(library path) -lsample.lib
```

> ld: library not found for -llibsample or -lsample or -lsample.lib
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command /Xcode Tools/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

How to add my lib file into Other linker flag?

Comment: The second example is the correct one. However, is the path correct? The first slash in marking the path as absolute, and is not part of the `-L` option.

Comment: Can you add the generated linker command?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the LD_LIBRARY_PATH because if the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not properly set then also this problem comes